# c++ function template parameter

Tags: c++

i wonder how can i compile this code..what should i do? i wrote the data type when i call the Sort function. and when i send the character array and int number as a parameter to Sort function , in Sort function , they can't change the char array as a int type i dont't know what should i do..

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>void Sort(T arr, int size);

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = { 33,42,5,87,39,72,15 };
    int num = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
    Sort(arr1, num);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << arr1[i] << " ";
    }
        cout << "\n";

    char arr2[5] = { 'C','E','G','F','U' };
    Sort<int>(arr2, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << arr2[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}

template <typename T>void Sort(T arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                T temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't just do `Sort<char>(arr2, 5)`?

Comment: You need a way to differentiate between an array and just a variable of a type, eg `T* arr` or `T arr[]`

Comment: Honestly, this should be done with iterators and potentially overloads, though the latter really isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't declare the `arr` parameter as an array, it's just a single variable.

```
template <typename T>void Sort(T arr[], int size);
```

or

```
template <typename T>void Sort(T *arr, int size);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Sort`, `temp` is not the correct type:

```
template <typename T>
void Sort(T arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                T temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should use `auto` instead of `T`, or create the swap function:

```
template <typename T>
void swap(T& t1, T& t2)
{
    // Real version would use move assignment instead of copy
    T temp = t1;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = temp;
}
```

And to be more generic, you could take your argument `arr` by reference (as currently, only usable by pointer, and you even don't use `T*` as arg). So your code now works also with `std::vector`, `std::array` for example.

```
template <typename T>
void Sort(T& arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i build a edited code, there are also some error in function declaration  char arr2 like this ->   Sort<char in here there is redline > (arr2, 5) do you know why?

Comment: You should let compiler deduce type so `Sort(arr2, 5);` if you want to provide type the correct ones would be `char*` (or `char[5]` without decay), so `Sort<char *>(arr2, 5);`

Comment: i really appreciate it thank you. but i still have some error.  can't  i write swap code in sort function ? if i use T temp as a variable at  when i sending char array   T temp would be char[5] temp . my problem is this and Sort function      Sort<char [5]>(arr2,5);                                                                            template <typename T>void Sort(T& arr, int size)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
 {
  for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
  {
   if (arr[i] > arr[j])
   {
    T temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: @gg.p: following https://ideone.com/j3mWUS are some working variations of your code as I can think. If that doesn't answer your problem, provide problematic code.

Comment: In your sample code, `T temp` is indeed invalid a `T`is the "array". `arr` and `arr[i]` have different (incompatible) types.

Comment: thank you  there is no more error any more. really really thank you!